# Computation of Confluent Hypergeometric Function of the First Kind in Matlab

Tags: matlab, math, wolfram-mathematica, physics

Is there a way to perform a computation of the confluent yypergeometric function of the first kind in Matlab (specifically in R2013a)?

In Mathematica, this function is called `Hypergeometric1F1`. I've seen `kummerU` in Matlab, but the definitions look different.

In Mathematica, the [definition is](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfluentHypergeometricFunctionoftheFirstKind.html):

[image: Hypergeometric1F1]

While in Matlab, the [definition is](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/kummeru.html) given as:

[image: kummeru]

How do I calculate confluent hypergeometric function of the first kind, i.e., the first of the two integrals, in Matlab?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two are different because they return different solutions to the same second order ODE, but the names can make them easy to confuse. Mathematica's [`Hypergeometric1F1`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hypergeometric1F1.html) calculates the [confluent hypergeometric function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfluentHypergeometricFunctionoftheFirstKind.html), also known as Kummer's function. Matlab's [`kummeru`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/kummeru.html) calculates the confluent hypergeometric Kummer *U* function, also known as Tricomi's confluent hypergeometric function. The two are related by a simple relation, [as shown here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function#Kummer.27s_equation) (see also the relations [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F1/27/01/) and [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/HypergeometricU/27/01/)).

In Matlab, you can calculate the confluent hypergeometric function symbolically via the general [`hypergeom`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/hypergeom.html) function (a numeric solution is returned if all of the input arguments are floating point):

```
A = hypergeom(a,b,z);
```

This will return a result equivalent to that from Mathematica's `Hypergeometric1F1`. If you need faster solutions, you can try my optimized [`hypergeomq`](https://github.com/horchler/hypergeomq) described in [this Math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/480175/80812). For a purely numeric solution, you could also try [this File Exchange submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29766-confluent-hypergeometric-function/content/kummer.m)

In Mathematica, you can use [`HypergeometricU`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HypergeometricU.html) to produce a result equivalent to Matlab's `kummeru`.